# jQuery search options for value and mark checked

Tags: jquery, json, forms, states

I have a database that I am pulling some states from, here is what the JSON I get back from it is:

```
["Arkansas","California","Connecticut","Florida"]
```

I have a list of all of the states in an option group, like follows:

```
<select name="geoStates" id="geoStates" class="select2" multiple>
<option></option>
<optgroup label="United States">
    <option value="Alabama" data-iconurl="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/23px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Alaska" data-iconurl="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/21px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png">Alaska</option>
    <option value="Arizona" data-iconurl="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/23px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png">Arizona</option>
    <option value="Arkansas" data-iconurl="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg/23px-Flag_of_Arkansas.svg.png">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="California" data-iconurl="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/23px-Flag_of_California.svg.png">California</option>
```

And so on for all of the states, is there a way for me to go through all of the values, and check the ones that I get back from the database based on the value of the option? This is something I have never had to do, so it is really tricky for me. :P

If I need to add anything, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
selected = ["Arkansas","California","Connecticut","Florida"];

$("#geoStates option").each(function(elem) {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), selected) != -1) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);    
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing it

http://jsfiddle.net/sQD8q/

Comment: I can see how this would work, but I am also using a jQuery plugin called Select2, and it makes the multi select look nicer, here is a look at what it looks like once it goes through the plugin, and I selected two different states to show what it looks like:
http://gyazo.com/c4593584e7e87c848588bbbedd00fe5b
How would I go about doing this with this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have been successful at storing the array you received from JSON into a JS array. If that is the case, you can simply iterate through each item in the array with [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), assuming that it is stored in a variable called `data`. During each iteration, we instruct jQuery to look for the option whose value matches that of in your `data` with a simple [CSS attribute selector](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/), `option[value='...']`.

```
// Just inserting data manually from your example. You should have fetched this with JSON instead
var data = ["Arkansas","California","Connecticut","Florida"];

// Iterate through array
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('#geoStates option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/k5sx7/

**Sidenote:** Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` ;) in the event you want to deselect, just use the line `$obj.prop('selected', false);` and not `.removeProp()`.

Comment: I can see how this would work, but I am also using a jQuery plugin called Select2, and it makes the multi select look nicer, here is a look at what it looks like once it goes through the plugin, and I selected two different states to show what it looks like: gyazo.com/c4593584e7e87c848588bbbedd00fe5b How would I go about doing this with this plugin? (COPIED COMMENT FROM ANOTHER ANSWER)

Comment: I believe the plugin will sniff for `.change()` in the element (if it doesn't, find a better plugin). You just have to trigger the event after iterating through the data, i.e. `$('#geoStates').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0):

Set the selected property of the options based on the values in the array, which you can check with jQuery's [$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
var states = ["Arkansas","California","Connecticut","Florida"];

$('#geoStates option').prop('selected', function() {
    return $.inArray(this.value, states) != -1;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vrwQB/)

Comment: Dayum, this is way more elegant than my answer ;)